# Flutter, cannot Write data to Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I can read data from Firestore, but cannot write data.
I confirm these writing function is not called, from firebase console. The problem occurs in local. How can I write data?

```dart
Future updateFavoriteArtists(List<Map> artists) async {
    List newlist = artists.map((e) => e['id']).toList();

    var ref =
        _db.collection('users').document(uid).collection('favorite_artists');

    var qs = await ref.getDocuments(); // this can read data.
    List<DocumentSnapshot> toDeleteList = List.from(qs.documents);
    toDeleteList.map((e) async => await e.reference.delete()); // this cannot delete data.

    List<Map> toAddList = List.from(artists);
    toAddList.map((e) {
      ref.document(e['id']).setData({'id': e['id'], 'name': e['name']}); // this cannot set data.
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please elaborate more...its unable to understand

Comment: From what I learn is the data is not updatind in app, are you accessing required firestore data from same file and also .updateData method should be present

Comment: Yes, I am not updating the data, but delete old ones and set new data into sub collection by `var ref`.

Comment: Make sure you have write permission to this reference in firestore rules.

Answer (score 0):

This solved by changing `toAddList.map` to `toAddList.forEach`. map function just return Iteration and not to be evaluated until someone call it.